# How to get yup.string() to require string of any length (including 0)

Tags: javascript, yup

I'm wondering if someone could advise me on how to get yup to validate strings of any length (including length 0).

Just using

```
yup.string().required().validateSync("")
```

will throw an error on an empty string...

In the past this was the recommended way to do it:

```
string().required().min(0)
```

but that way no longer works.. (https://github.com/jquense/yup/issues/136#issuecomment-339235070)

Can someone advise me on how to get yup to require that a string is sent, but to not error on length 0 strings?

Thanks!

Comment: `required()` will make the validation false if the string is empty, you will have to remove `required()`.

Comment: @FletcherRipp I still want to throw an error though if the string is simply absent. IMO there is a difference between an empty string and no string at all

Comment: The `string()` method validates the data type while `required()` checks if there is anything at all and if a string is empty (`""`). So wouldn't `yup.string()` be all the validation you'll want because all you really want to know is check the data type is a `String`.

Comment: @FletcherRipp I think you're incorrect there. See this codesandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/priceless-margulis-1zkot?file=/src/index.js I want the first validateSync to throw an error as well..

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you want you said you want "the first one" to send an error and it does because `undefined !== String` from what I think you are asking for you want something that will validate a string of any length including empty (`""`) but you don't want it to validate `undefined` or `null` is that right?

Comment: Correct, the answer from undefined below does exactly what I'm looking for.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/221650/discussion-between-fletcher-ripp-and-majorbummer).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What I would suggest would be to drop the `.required()` and, instead, look at using `typeError` for your validation whilst enabling `strict` to stop non-string values being coerced and transformed.

This will enable you to allow string values of any length whilst still erroring on values which are not strings.

Example:

```js
yup.string().typeError().strict(true).validateSync(1) // Error
yup.string().typeError().strict(true).validateSync(null) // Error
yup.string().typeError().strict(true).validateSync({}) // Error
yup.string().typeError().strict(true).validateSync("") // Valid
yup.string().typeError().strict(true).validateSync("Foo") // Valid
```

`typeError` also has an optional `message` parameter allowing you to provide the error message there and then if you don't wish to handle it again later.

Comment: This doesn't actually work, because `undefined` passes the validation

Answer (score 7):

```
yup.string().defined().strict(true);
```

This will work for `undefined` values as well.

Comment: This seems to work correctly to me, although I'm not quite sure WHY it works, based on reading the Yup docs. And since the schema type is still string here, you can still use string methods like `max` and `matches`.

Answer (score 2):

I like using `mixed` ,  `test` and `typeof === 'string'`:

```
    firstName: Yup.mixed().test(
        'my test',
        'error: name is not a string',
        (text) => {
            if (typeof text === 'string') {
                return true
            } else {
                return false
            }
        }
    )
```

Answer (score 0):

###### `Required String that can be Empty`

Example Field called: `relevance_factor` that has the same requirements as yours

```js
let relevance_factor = yup
    .string()
    .test(
        'string-can-be-empty',
        MESSAGES.RELEVANCE_FACTOR_REQUIRED,
        function stringCanBeEmpty(value: any) {
            if (typeof value == 'string')
                return true;

            return false;
        }
    )
```